# Which browsers have support for CSS :before { content: "x"; }

Tags: css, browser, cross-browser, pseudo-element

Which browsers have support for CSS :before { content: "x"; }? I could not find any information about this question. It seems that the CSS attribute content is quite unknown in the community although seemingly useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for the [**Quirksmode compatibility tables**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter.html).

> Not supported by IE7 and lower.
>
> IE8b1 doesn't accept images as content.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t15.